# Error while contacting Elastic Beanstalk Service?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, runtime-error

I've created an Elastic Beanstalk application, run the `eb init` command(all this in the EU Frankfurt server), but when I try to run `eb create` I get this:

```
Uploading: [--------------------------------------------------] 0% 2015-07-08 08:18:50,220 (ERROR) ebcli.lib.aws : Error while contacting Elastic Beanstalk Service
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I'm trying to deploy a Django project, in case that's useful...

Comment: Any luck finding the culprit? I'm able to deploy succesfully, but every once in a while I see this error as well "(ERROR) ebcli.lib.aws : Error while contacting Elastic Beanstalk Service". Despite the errors, the deployment is successful. I started having issues after migrating from eb 2.x to EB CLI 3 and deploying with eb deploy.

Comment: Deleted my account, had no money to pay after a while...